# Is there any way to provide left margin on y axis label to avoid the chart moving Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using Chart JS for bar representation. and using this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-scrollable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for scrolling the bar chart.

In vertical bar, everything working fine. But in horizontal bar while scrolling the y axis moving.
It is because of the characters length the chart is moving on scroll.

[image: In this image u can see the position of the chart]

In the above picture, you can see the chart position.

[image: second picture]

this is second picture the chart position slightly moves to left.

i Know this is because of the character, I have tried some logic like adding empty spaces based on maximum character shown to other words which is less than the bigger words.

Is there any way to make it fixed without moving. or can we try adding margin left before y axis label, if yes how to add a margin to it. Because in highchart I have seen something like margin left fixes this thing, But I don't know how to implement in chartjs

Comment: Have you tried adding some padding to the left as described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html#top-left-bottom-right-object)? And there's also an option to set `backdropPadding` for the ticks.

Comment: No it is not working. still has that movement while scolling, since the chartjs is auto scaling the chart based on max characters visible. I have also done some logic like if i only want to display max 20 characters. i have slice to 17 and add ... after it. for value less than 20 i have add empty spaces before it. but still the movement it happening it is because the the character sizes for example 'j' take little width then 'w'.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-scrollable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, In this link itself you can see if you add move character and scroll this will jumps

Comment: @IvanTsenilov For now I have found a solution which is, making every labels in equal length for example adding spaces on before labels. And I have used font family monospaces don't to have equal width characters. And now the jumping is not happening.

Comment: @KumaravelA switching to monospace font did the trick for me when trying to pad labels with whitespace that were too short, thanks!